# JavaScript : Identifying what was changed between two strings

Tags: javascript, string, comparison, indexing, diff

**Ok this is my problem:** I want produce a rich text editor when a user can make changes to a large block of text. I then want to be able to identify not only what parts of the document were changed, but most importantly the character index at which these changes happened.

By knowing what was changed I want to be able to replicate those exact changes to a clone of the original document.

I have looked briefly into:

http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/

http://ejohn.org/projects/javascript-diff-algorithm/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Cacycle/diff.js

**Does anyone know the best way to go about this?**

P.S. I know it sounds like a complicated requirement but for what I am building it is neccessary.

Comment: Hhhmmm... is your "clone" of the original document the exact same as your original text in the editor?  It has to be, otherwise your "patch" won't work identically.  However, if it is, what's wrong with just replacing the the original document with the new version?

Comment: @stephenChung it is a real-time application meaning it is possible someone is working on another version of the original document at the same time and only changes must be inserted so as not to overwrite any changes they have made themselves. Does this make sense?

Comment: well it doesn't make sense.  Say the person inserts a character at position 80.  You can't just go ahead an insert that same character at position 80 in the original document if somebody else has already edited it.  You have to "lock" the original document so that there are no more possible editors, or alert the user that the document has changed and his edits are now invalid.